# How to sign a raw multisig transaction from an external private key

Tags: transactions, multi-signature, raw-transaction, createrawtransaction, bcoin

I am creating a 2-of-3 multisig wallet, where the 2 hot keys are external HSM devices.
I am using Bcoin to create my transactions.
After the transactions are created, I will send the raw transaction to an external application to do the signing.

My question is, which part exactly needs to be signed by the private key?

For example, this is my transaction:

```
{
    "hash": "e82c7bdfc864ab4d0592045dd86b81a438eeee77f8415c0a84e1aa0ea8e17786",
    "witnessHash": "e82c7bdfc864ab4d0592045dd86b81a438eeee77f8415c0a84e1aa0ea8e17786",
    "fee": 1000000,
    "rate": 4424778,
    "mtime": 1568880046,
    "version": 1,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "prevout": {
                "hash": "3b1dd17cc82e2ac43ba62bf8f1c6a0fe805df43911653d22c902571eb3a212ce",
                "index": 0
            },
            "script": "000000004c6952210209ad6cf408e41362fa175d5869e4561f1890c0d8d74353c86095fdecde34459721024a92aa3f883cc4438b75205555e517a4f7cc10ffd42517297a17821ae6f0bb8821037d2a259a52f62fee96fea072844139224fbd9027116ac7582025dd446fc73e3e53ae",
            "witness": "00",
            "sequence": 4294967295,
            "coin": {
                "version": 1,
                "height": -1,
                "value": 10000000000,
                "script": "a9144de6d3580732a7c7c2b1eb043cb1b89350c265fa87",
                "address": "38nvUMbXFdXDp4PTWvbohCbnPJuLUVwzXr",
                "coinbase": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "value": 5000000000,
            "script": "a91481be67198d33319415d09b03f2dc2cfa4cdb42aa87",
            "address": "3DX3BhmdRGf5vYbtzHKzazGmZ7WgUkhFRk"
        },
        {
            "value": 4999000000,
            "script": "a9144de6d3580732a7c7c2b1eb043cb1b89350c265fa87",
            "address": "38nvUMbXFdXDp4PTWvbohCbnPJuLUVwzXr"
        }
    ],
    "locktime": 0,
    "hex": "0100000001ce12a2b31e5702c9223d651139f45d80fea0c6f1f82ba63bc42a2ec87cd11d3b000000006f000000004c6952210209ad6cf408e41362fa175d5869e4561f1890c0d8d74353c86095fdecde34459721024a92aa3f883cc4438b75205555e517a4f7cc10ffd42517297a17821ae6f0bb8821037d2a259a52f62fee96fea072844139224fbd9027116ac7582025dd446fc73e3e53aeffffffff0200f2052a0100000017a91481be67198d33319415d09b03f2dc2cfa4cdb42aa87c0aff6290100000017a9144de6d3580732a7c7c2b1eb043cb1b89350c265fa8700000000"
}
```

If you decode the `script` in the `inputs` it is:

```
OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 OP_0 52210209ad6cf408e41362fa175d5869e4561f1890c0d8d74353c86095fdecde34459721024a92aa3f883cc4438b75205555e517a4f7cc10ffd42517297a17821ae6f0bb8821037d2a259a52f62fee96fea072844139224fbd9027116ac7582025dd446fc73e3e53ae
```

As you can see there are 4 `OP_0` **placeholders** to input the signatures.
Now my question is, which part of the transaction the external signing application should sign. Is it just the `000000004c6952210209ad6cf408e41362fa175d5869e4561f1890c0d8d74353c86095fdecde34459721024a92aa3f883cc4438b75205555e517a4f7cc10ffd42517297a17821ae6f0bb8821037d2a259a52f62fee96fea072844139224fbd9027116ac7582025dd446fc73e3e53ae`
part?

Any reference is highly appreciated.
I have read https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction and https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG but I can't figure out for sure.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bitcoin Wiki entry for OP_CHECKSIG answers your question. OP_CHECKMULTISIG works the same way, just applied to each signature in the sequence.

First of all, it depends on the SIGHASH type you, as the signer, choose. Most likely you will use the default `SIGHASH_ALL` for each of the required signatures, but you could actually use different SIGHASH methods for each individual signature.

Since you mentioned bcoin, you can review the signature hash methods in `lib/primitives/tx.js` [here](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/blob/6a46a586eeae4332513c9d2293553ca0bf5473c8/lib/primitives/tx.js#L441), and in the methods immediately following.

Very briefly:

The SIGHASH_ALL method will serialize all the inputs* and all the outputs of the transaction, including the `nLocktime`, and sign that blob.

*The input scripts are all replaced with a sinlge `0x00` byte. The script of the input being signed/checked is replaced by the corresponding output script from the funding transaction. So actually, the hex string you posted (the templated input script `000000004c695...`) is the only part of the transaction that will NOT be signed by any of the multisig participants for this input!

*bonus tidbit:* The 2-of-3 signature template has FOUR `OP_0`'s. Why? Well. the first one is popped off the stack by `OP_CHECKMULTISIG`, that's a bug Satoshi left us with. The other three are placeholders for the actual signatures. There are THREE instead of just TWO because the signatures need to be in the same order as the pubKeys in the redeem script. The extra placeholder is removed before broadcasting the transaction. In bcoin, this script template is assembled [here](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/blob/6a46a586eeae4332513c9d2293553ca0bf5473c8/lib/primitives/mtx.js#L596-L614).

Comment: thank you very much. Can you please elaborate what will be signed in the case there are multiple inputs with different multisig scripts for each of them. Each time the transaction is signed, are all the inputs replaced by `0x00` for all the inputs? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, in SIGHASH_ALL, each input signs the same scheme: `0x00` for every input script _except_ the input being signed, where the script is replaced with the previous txs' output script.